# Ubuntu 12.10: Can't change window title bar font

Tags: fonts, window-manager, 12.10, ubuntu-tweak

In Ubuntu 12.10 Beta 2, I've tried using Ubuntu Tweak to change the window title bar font, but after it's changed in the application, it's not reflected throughout the system. I've tried different fonts at different sizes with no luck; the window title font and size stay the same.

I know this is a beta release, but all the other fonts change on the system when I change them in Ubuntu Tweak.  The other fonts (Default, desktop, monospace, etc.) update when they're changed. Just not the window title bar font.

Comment: Have you tried MyUbuntu? Also, if it's a Ubuntu Tweak problem, you should [report a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak).

Comment: Have you installed all available updates in the Update Manager, bringing your 12.10 beta system to the current stable 12.10? If so, and you are still experiencing this problem, then we should probably reopen this question, even though it might end up being re-closed as off topic if the behavior being described turns out to be due to a bug.

Comment: This worked in 12.04, but in 12.10 tweek tool can't change the fonts at least in the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you use [gnome-tweak-tool [image: Install gnome-tweak-tool]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-tweak-tool) to change the title bar font. As of this writing, it works just fine for me.

[image: gnome-tweak-tool]

---

To install `gnome-tweak-tool`, run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to help in Kubuntu.  On upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10, the default desktop font and all title windows have reverted from my FreeSans (nicer IMHO) to the narrow and harder to read 'Ubuntu' font. gnome-tweak-tool shows the wanted font correctly as 'FreeSans' (and so does KDE 'system-settings') but it doesn't actually reflect on the desktop, window titles, etc.

Comment: Ofcourse it won't work in Kubuntu. It is tweak tool for gnome (only affects gnome-shell, Unity and gnome-fallback)

Comment: This method worked for me. After completing the upgrade to 12.10, Ubuntu Tweak still wasn't working for changing the title bars, but this did.

Comment: Does this work on 14.04?

Comment: @Pisek Try unity-tweak-tool on 14.04.